# Session Data is not updating

Tags: node.js, express, memcached, express-session

I m using `express-session` and `memcached-connect` package for maintaining session.
Everything is working as expected.

Here is my implementation:

Middleware

```
app.use(session({
    rolling: true,
    secret: 'iloveexpress',
    proxy: 'true',
    store: new MemcachedStore({
        hosts: ['127.0.0.1:11211']
    }),
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 86400000,
        path: "/",
        domain: 'example.com'
    }, //1 Day
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: true
}));
```

Setting Session

```
req.session.data = {
   id: '123,
   name: 'ABC',
   amount: 1000,
   profilePic: '/images/asd.jpg'
}
```

Updating Session

```
req.session.data.amount = 500;
```

But when I update a particular data in the session, it not updating. The other time I make a request to the Api its showing the old data, i.e., `amount = 1000;`

**EDIT:**
console of req.session

```
Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2017-09-20T07:11:35.394Z,
     originalMaxAge: 86399951,
     httpOnly: true,
     domain: 'example.com' },
  data:
   { id: '591173362ad30b419e2c4f54',
     name: 'ABC',
     amount: 1000,
     profilePic: '/image/1496663576532Koala.jpg' } }
```

Comment: Could you console.log your req.session and show that?  Just so we know exactly what the current session is for all values?

Comment: I have added it. Please have a look.

Comment: Not sure if this will work, but try explicitly setting your cookie to cookie: { secure: false} in the middle ware.  If its defaulting true that basically means that the cookie will only be set on https calls which could be your problem

Comment: It did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old one, but I had the same problem and fixed it by setting the cookie option :

secure: true

Answer (score 0):

Hey I don't If this applies in your case but if you are updating the session variables in the post method use: `req.session.save()` after updating the variable